# вызов команд PowerShell для ExchangeServer 2010 из приложения C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Приложение должно выполнить команды по созданию mailbox например. Запускаться в локальной сетке, но не с машины где стоит сам Exchange. 
Есть у кого примерчик?

Comment: выполнить удаленную команду можно